# Does an image editor library cross-platform for xamarin exists?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I need to implement some sort of library that allows me to pick (one or multiple), edit, crop, resize, move and apply other effects on user's photos that will be sent to a server later.
I tried to write my own code to do so but it takes much more time and it's quite difficult.
Do you know some libs (open-source or not) that give me the chance to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For editing I know:

1. Media plugin https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin
2. UCrop: https://github.com/NAXAM/ucrop-android-binding
3. You can bind **any** library from native to xamarin

Answer (score 0):

Just use SkiaSharp, its free has tons of documentation and is cross-platfrom